# How render latex fonts and formulas in Cairo C?

Tags: c, svg, ffmpeg, latex, cairo

I've tried the next steps:

1. A standalone tex file:

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}

\[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3=\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}i \right)^2 \]

\end{document}
```

2. I've compiled with this:

```
latex file.tex
```

It means: `pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=latex)` to got the `dvi` file.

3. Transform my `dvi` to `svg` with the next:

```
dvisvgm --libgs=/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3/lib/libgs.9.53.dylib file.dvi
```

#### Here I got the first trouble

When I open my `svg` it render with fake symbols in `Chrome`, but in `Safari` I obtain a success with it. However I discard that and I continue with Cairo.

```c
#include <cairo.h>
#include <librsvg/rsvg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    cairo_surface_t *surface;
    cairo_t *cr;
    RsvgHandle *handle;

    /* Code */

    if( (handle = rsvg_handle_new_from_file("file.svg", NULL)) == NULL ){
        printf("Error trying to load a SVG file\n");
    }

    if( rsvg_handle_render_cairo(handle, cr) != TRUE ){
        printf("Error trying to draw a SVG file\n");
    }

    cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "image.png");
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

    return 0;

}
```

And I render this:

[image: result]

That symbols are the same in `Chrome`. When I open my `svg` it looks at last lines like this:

```xml
<text class='f1' x='138.107022' y='-25.204175'>n</text>
<text class='f4' x='133.374191' y='-22.215398'></text>
<text class='f1' x='134.116478' y='-0.996264'>i</text>
<text class='f3' x='136.935205' y='-0.996264'>=1</text>
<text class='f0' x='149.425099' y='-12.750829'>i</text>
<text class='f3' x='152.857357' y='-16.864325'>3</text>
<text class='f2' x='160.09406' y='-12.750829'>=</text>
<text class='f4' x='170.610139' y='-29.787102'></text>
<text class='f1' x='183.230082' y='-25.204175'>n</text>
<text class='f4' x='178.49725' y='-22.215398'></text>
<text class='f1' x='179.239538' y='-0.996264'>i</text>
<text class='f3' x='182.058265' y='-0.996264'>=1</text>
<text class='f0' x='194.548158' y='-12.750829'>i</text>
<text class='f4' x='197.980417' y='-29.787102'></text>
<text class='f3' x='205.867527' y='-27.722624'>2</text>
```

So something fail.

In the other hand I'de like to say that `pig-config --cflags librsvg-2.0` shows the right output but when I read the Headers there's a `WARNING` there about Cairo users:

```c
#if !defined (__RSVG_RSVG_H_INSIDE__) && !defined (RSVG_COMPILATION)
#warning "Including <librsvg/rsvg-cairo.h> directly is deprecated."
#endif

#ifndef RSVG_CAIRO_H
#define RSVG_CAIRO_H

#include <cairo.h>
```

And that's the reason to include `rsvg` header instead of `Cairo-svg` cause it includes that yet:

```c
#ifndef RSVG_H
#define RSVG_H

#define __RSVG_RSVG_H_INSIDE__

#include <glib-object.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

#include <cairo.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

/* Code and Defs */

G_END_DECLS

#include "librsvg-features.h"
#include "rsvg-cairo.h"
```

But there's no any documentation about it.

And the last question:

#### What's the best way to render a latex formula in a mp4 video format?

I mean, I've tried with Cairo and then put it in a video. but There's better results rendering that formula directly with `FFMPEG`? I found some results with `python` but sincerely I'm tired with it. I'm looking for different ways. The purpose in this: Use `C` code.

Comment: If your end goal is a mp4, a pixelated format, why not produce a png from your formula and include this? All advantages for vector graphics will be lost anyway when you convert it into mp4

Comment: I agree with samcarter. But if you want to use SVGs, you can call dvisvgm with option `--no-fonts` which converts all font data to paths. The resulting SVG is usually more portable and will probably render correctly with Cairo.